# Open contextMenu of the element without physically clicking

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xpath, contextmenu

I tried to manipulate this code I found in internet. This is useful to me in clicking links. But theres some cases I need to use the right click function to open the contextMenu of that element.

Please see this code if theres a way you can convert this to open contextMenu.

I tried to manipulate it with some codes to put inside, but no success.

```
(function run (pXPathStr) {
  'use strict';

var ptyScriptName   = "Click on Link Identified by XPath"

/*
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
PURPOSE:  Click on the Hyperlink Identified by the XPath provided by KM

RETURNS:  One of these, as text:
  • "OK" -- if successful, no errors
    
  • "[ERROR]" at start of results if a script error occurred.
  
KM VARIABALES REQUIRED:
  • xPath    -- the full XPath to the Link
  
    EXAMPLE XPATH:
    //*[@id="ctl00_MainContent_ucEStatements_dlStatements_ctl00_lbStatementDate"]

KM VARIABLES SET:
  • NONE
  
REF:
  • [Introduction to using XPath in JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Introduction_to_using_XPath_in_JavaScript)
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
*/
  //--- GET THE XPATH FROM KM ---
  var xPathStr = document.kmvar.xPath;
  
  var returnResults = "TBD";
  
  //--- GET THE HTML ELEMENT IDENTIFIED BY THE XPATH ---
  var elemFound =  document.evaluate(
      xPathStr, document, null, 0, null
    ).iterateNext();
    
  if (elemFound) {
    //--- CLICK ON THE LINK ---
    elemFound.click();
    returnResults = "";
  }
  else {
    //--- ERROR:  ELEMENT WAS NOT FOUND ---
    returnResults = '[ERROR] Element NOT FOUND for XPath:\n' + xPathStr;
    alert(returnResults);
  }
  
  return returnResults;

})();

/* 
*/
```

I expect running this function will do open contextMenu of the element.

I will use contextMenu on image elements to download to my desktop.

Here is the image of menu I want to open after the right click action in the link.
[The is the action result in the image link I want to happen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lTJ3b.jpg)

[Right - Click Menu I want to open after right Click, and the Highlighted blue color Is what I will click next. But I can easily call this by pressing Key "S" then enter to download image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UhT0W.png)

Comment: How do you intend to invoke this script?

Comment: I will use it to get the right-click menu in the target link using xpath. Then I will choose the download image,